# Detect safe area insets on Share Extension

Tags: ios11, iphone-x, share-extension, safearealayoutguide

I'm adapting an app to support iPhone X. I have a share extension with a custom view controller. I need to know the safe area insets of my device, but the `safeAreaInsets` method from `UIWindow` provided by calling `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` isn't available in the Share Extension because `UIApplication.shared` is not visible there.
Is there a way to know the values from the `safeAreaInsets` property in my Share Extension?

Answer (score 7):

`safeAreaInsets` is a property on any UIView; you can use that in your Share Extension. You don't need to ask `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` for safeAreaInsets - in fact, you probably don't want to do that, because if the keyWindow contains a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`, those would affect the safeAreaInsets.

If you have a view deep in your `UIView` hierarchy, its `safeAreaInsets` are calculated by looking at ancestor views in the hierarchy, and seeing if any of them have `safeAreaInsets` that overlap with your view.

You may find, however, that the `safeAreaInsets` are initially `UIEdgeInsets.zero` - what you'll want to do is implement `UIView.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()` or `UIViewController.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()`, like so:

```
public override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints() // or self.setNeedsLayout, etc.
    }
}
```